# Tool for deploying web-project to the server

Tags: web-apps, web-development, project-management, sql-server, web-server

I don't need a recommendation, but need a tool name or, at least, a name of such tools (probably, language barrier).

I am looking for a tool which will help me to deploy a project to the server.

What am I doing now?

1. work with project
2. work with base
3. turn off site (under construction)
4. open my monstrous FTP and upload ALL files (1000+ with media)
5. update database
6. turn on site

What am I looking for?

So, I am looking for a tool, which will compare snapshot of the files on the server and on my working folder (like GitHub or any other svn) and will only:

1. upload new files
2. upload and rewrite old files, which has some editions
3. highly prefer to upload the database on the server

Comment: Is the database ftp/filesytem accessible or SSH/CmdLine? depending on your server setup you may not be able to automatedly upload teh database updates.

Comment: @NickWilde Hm. I have simple hosting (not vdc or dc). I have access to my hosting by ssh. How I can check mysql availability? I tried to type `mysql`, but it says this: [image](http://i.gyazo.com/af04b38fa684b8c502a7d61112219ff7.png)

Comment: I will write to support and will ask about it

Comment: That's a configuration issue. You cannot connect remotely via socket (that's only available locally), you need to do that over IP.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Heroku](https://heroku.com) before? You can push to it just like [Github](https://github.com/).

Well, you can do the same on your own host if you have root access by installing git and setting up a hook that will check out the code to your webserver's folder. A detailed how-to for this can be found [here on Toroid.ORG](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto).

Comment: That's a good one! I'm just starting with git and chose a similar project to get used to it. This was exactly the missing part (setup my own "remote repository" and have a kind of "auto-deployment", which I currently do with `rsync`). +1 from me, even before testing it :)

Answer (score 1):

[Saltstack](http://saltstack.com/) will do everything that you're asking for.

[Here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/walkthrough.html)'s a good place to start using saltstack.